# How to print like this in vue js?

Tags: vue.js

```
        [![Output Screenshot][1]][1]
        
        

My Code :
            <template>
              <div>
                <div class="timeline">
                  <div class="spine"></div>
                  <div class="date_separator">
                    <span>Today - {{ today }}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <ul
                      class="columns"
                      v-for="index in userPlanCount"          
                      :key="index"          
                    >
                      <li>
                        <div class="timeline_element">
                          <div class="timeline_title">
                            <span class="timeline_label"> {{ allGroupNames[index] }} </span
                            >&nbsp;<span class="timeline_date">{{
                              allGroupDates[index]
                            }}</span>
                          </div>
                          <table                    
                          >
                            <thead>
                              <tr>
                                <th>   
                                   <span > Profile Name </span>
                                </th>
                                <th>Created</th>
                                <th></th>
                              </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody >
                              <tr>
                                <td>{{ allGroupNames[index] }}</td>
                                <td>{{ allGroupDates[index] }}</td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <div class="timeline_element">
                          <div class="timeline_title">
                            <span class="timeline_label">
                              {{ allGroupNames[index+1] }} </span
                            >&nbsp;<span class="timeline_date">{{
                              allGroupDates[index+1]
                            }}</span>
                          </div>
                          <table
                            
                          >
                            <thead>
                              <tr>
                                <th>
                                  
                                  <span> Profile Name </span>
                                </th>
                                <th>Created</th>
                                <th></th>
                              </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td>{{ allGroupNames[index+1] }}</td>
                                <td>{{ allGroupDates[index+1] }}</td>                  
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </div>            
                      </li>                    
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </template>
    
    <script>
    
    export default {
      
      data() {
        return {
          today: moment(Date.now()).format("DD MMM YYYY"),
          allGroupDates: [],
          allGroupNames: [],
          edition: "",
          userPlanCount: "",
          userDetails: [],
          allProfileName: [],
          allProfileDate: [],    
        };
      },
      mounted() {
        this.getUserPlanHistory();
      },
      // method
      methods: {
        
        getUserPlanHistory() {
          var data = {
            userId: this.userId,
            accountId: this.userAccountId,
          };
          this.$store.dispatch("getPlanHistoryDetails", data).then(
            (response) => {
              this.allGroupNames = response.message.allGroupNames;
              this.allGroupDates = response.message.allGroupDates;
              this.edition = response.message.edition;
              this.userPlanCount = response.message.userPlanCount;
              this.allProfileName = response.message.allProfileName;
              this.allProfileDate = response.message.allProfileDate;
              this.allGroupDates.reverse();
              this.allGroupNames.reverse();
              this.allProfileDate.reverse();
              this.allProfileName.reverse();
            },
            (error) => {
              console.log(error);
            }
          );
        },
      },
    };
    </script>
```

Thank you in advance for the solution. This is the full code of I was previously posted of some part of the code. For Example : In this code, index starts with '0'. it prints 0th index value and 1st index value, in 1st li and in 2nd li respectively. Then, the index gets incremented and the value becomes '1'. But, it prints again 1st index value and 2nd index value and so on. So, how to increment the index value after it prints 0th index and 1st index values. I added the screenshot of output for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is within your `v-for` statement.

When looping through an **array** with `v-for` the syntax for getting the index and item is`v-for="(item, index) in array`

If you want to just loop a certain number of times you can use `v-for="index in number", but it seems like the variable you're looping through is a string, not a number.

Alternatively, you could do away with `userPlanCount` altogether and use the `length` property of whatever object you're looping through.